# How to check for missing elements in two array lists of different objects, in Java?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, data-structures

I have two classes with different properties and only one with a common one. I want to compare the two and extract a list with missing elements. So for example we have the following classes where inventoryId and id are the same and these are elements we'll be looking for, if they're missing in drug list.

```
public class DrugInventory {
    String inventoryId;
    String drugStatus;
}

public class Drug{
    String id;
    String name;
    String quantity;
}
```

`inventoryID` in `DrugInventory` is equal to `id` in `Drug`. So these are two values I'll be looking if they're missing in the Drug list.

```
List<DrugInventory> drugInventories = new ArrayList<>();

DrugInventory drugInventory = new DrugInventory("121212");
DrugInventory drugInventory1 = new DrugInventory("232323");
DrugInventory drugInventory2 = new DrugInventory("343434");
DrugInventory drugInventory3 = new DrugInventory("454545");
DrugInventory drugInventory4 = new DrugInventory("565656");

drugInventories.add(drugInventory);
drugInventories.add(drugInventory1);
drugInventories.add(drugInventory2);
drugInventories.add(drugInventory3);
drugInventories.add(drugInventory4);

List<Drug> drugs = new ArrayList<>();

Drug drug = new Drug("121212");
Drug drug1 = new Drug("232323");
Drug drug2 = new Drug("343434");

drugs.add(drug);
drugs.add(drug1);
drugs.add(drug2);
```

The expected result here should be equal to a list looking like this:

```
 [DrugInventory(inventoryId=454545, drugStatus=null), DrugInventory(inventoryId=565656, drugStatus=null)]
```

I can use nested loops here to compare each element but that would be inefficient. How can I do it efficiently?

Comment: Hi Farooq! I would recommend to edit the title to make it clear that you are asking about performance. Also it would be easier to read with simpler ID.

Comment: Lists are inherently bad at the kinds of lookups you're looking for.  If you need to be able to find an object by ID it might be worth looking into a Map.  Possibly a temporarily generated one if you're willing to take the memory hit for lower complexity lookup.

Comment: @Thomas I appreciate the idea. So what would be our strategy if we use maps here?

Comment: Farooq, are you bound to use lists, or can you use other data structures? If you don't care about the order, you could use Sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the specific problem of finding the drugs in inventory that do not exist in the drug list, you can use:

```
public static List<DrugInventory> findMissingDrugs(List<Drug> drugs, 
                                                   List<DrugInventory> inventory) {
    Set<String> drugIdLookup = drugs.stream()
                                    .map(d -> d.id)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
    return inventory.stream()
                    .filter(i->!drugIdLookup.contains(i.inventoryId))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());      
}
```

First, we pull just the IDs into a `HashSet` (`HashSet` offers O(1) lookup time complexity), then we collect everything from inventory which isn't in that lookup set. If you have more complex lookups where you need to use multiple keys, then the other answer about restructuring both into `HashMap`s where the IDs are keys is a better long term approach.

Comment: It just returns the drugInventories List.
Expected: 
`[DrugInventory(inventoryId=454545, drugStatus=null), DrugInventory(inventoryId=565656, drugStatus=null)]`

Actual: 
`[DrugInventory(inventoryId=121212, drugStatus=null, DrugInventory(inventoryId=232323, drugStatus=null,  DrugInventory(inventoryId=343434, drugStatus=null), DrugInventory(inventoryId=454545, drugStatus=null, DrugInventory(inventoryId=565656, drugStatus=null)]`

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  I fed your sample input into it and got the expected two in output.

Comment: Something was wrong in my code. Your solution works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

- Create a `Map<String, DrugInventory>` and a `Map<String, Drug>`, e.g. using HashMap as implementation.
- Add drug and drug inventory objects into the respective map with put using the id and inventoryId fields of each object as first and the object as second parameter.
- Create a set of the combined key values of both maps using Map's keySet method.
- Iterate over those keys and retrieve a drug and drug inventory object from the respective map. If both are non-null for a particular key you have a match and can print out the details in which you are interested with System.out.println.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 solutions. One with extra space and another without extra space. It's trade of between space and time complexity, whichever best suits you. Sample code snippets below...

**1. Sort Drugs by, and binary Search for each element of Drug Inventory(inventoryId).**

```
    // Sort Drug by id
    Comparator<Drug> drugComparator = new Comparator<Drug>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Drug d1, Drug d2) {
            return d1.id.compareTo(d2.id);
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(drugs, drugComparator);

    for (DrugInventory inventory : drugInventories) {
        if (!binarySearch(drugs, inventory.inventoryId)) {
            System.out.println(inventory.inventoryId);
        }
    }

    public static boolean binarySearch(List<Drug> drugs, String drugInventory) {

    int left = 0;
    int right = drugs.size() - 1;

    while (left <= right) {
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        int comapare = drugs.get(middle).id.compareTo(drugInventory);
        if (comapare == 0) {
            return true;
        } else if (comapare < 0) {
            left = middle + 1;
        } else {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**2. Use HashSet add and remove the elements(id/inventoryId), remaining id's in set will be missing id's.**

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    // Add drug inventories to set
    for (DrugInventory inventoryElement : drugInventories) {
        set.add(inventoryElement.inventoryId);
    }

    // Remove drugs from set
    for (Drug drugElement : drugs) {
        set.remove(drugElement.id);
    }

    // Remaining entries in set are missing entries
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
```